# RadioButton in ListView ripple effect

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, material-design, ripple-effect

I have problem with `RadioButton` ripple effect. I **want** get this: [I have ripple in full background of list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Dm1.gif)

[image]

but I **have** this: [I have ripple only around mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLv0E.gif)

[image]

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CheckedTextView` in `ListView` with `SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Apply click listener on itemView and in that listener check radio button as
true or false. Change the backgroundTint  to required color of radio button.

Comment: No, I want to change the shape of the ripple effect, not the color.

Answer (score 0):

Ripple effect is available for API-level 21+ you can apply it to Radio buttons with
`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` for each individual button

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Option number one" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Option number two" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. It has no effect.